# How to parse JSON returned from a webservice in swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift, web-services

Hey i am new to swift and I need to parse this JSON and get the value of "name" returned from a webservice:

```
{name = "Sameer Hussain";}
```

Here is my code so far:

```
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx.php")!
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
    var bodyData = "data=something"
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    //request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    {
            (response, data, error) in
           // println(data)
            var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            //println(strData)
            var err1: NSError?
            var json2 = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(strData!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err1 ) as! NSDictionary!
            println("\(json2)")
    }
```

Comment: what does your returned data look like. Is it returning an array of objects or something else. Seeing the JSON format would be helpful to answer the question.

Comment: i have mentioned above {name = "Sameer Hussain";}
So far it just returns this

Comment: see answer below, it might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code above it seems like your data is being saved within the  json2 variable. To retrieve a value from that variable you can try something like this.

```
var userName: String?
var userAge: Int?
var userEmail: String?

if let parseJSON = json2
            {
                 userName = parseJSON["name"] as? String
                 userAge  = parseJSON["age"] as? Int
                 userEmail = parseJSON["email"] as? String
            }
```

The above would work if your returned JSON looks something like this:

```
            {
                "name": "John"
                "age": "21"
                "email": "john@gmail.com"

            }
```

Comment: Thanks. 
when i  do this: 
println(userName)

It prints something like this on console:

Optional("Sameer Hussain")

What's optional here?

Comment: You need to unwrap the optional variable: `println(userName!)`

Comment: you need to unwrap the value. Try doing println(userName!). If you think this worked please select as answer

Comment: @Phoen1xUK beat me by 8 sec haha

Comment: Thank you guys and sorry for such basic questions :)

Comment: @SameerHussain I asked the same question a few months ago. Happy Coding mate!